# Colocar un subtítulo de anotación por debajo del eje X

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

He creado un código para una gráfica sencilla usando matplotlib, lo que busco es agregar un subtítulo de anotación con letra cursiva en la parte de abajo del eje x, he revisado algunas documentaciones pero no he encontrado algo que pueda aplicar para este caso. Intenté definir una variable que almacene ese otro subtítulo pero se reemplaza con el primero, si conocen algún método lo agradecería.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 25), dpi=80)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 24)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 16)

h = 0.15 * 1000
bf = 0.1 * 1000
tw = 0.0085 * 1000

ax.add_patch( Rectangle((bf/2 - tw/2, 0), tw, h, fc ='black',zorder=2 ) ) 
ax.add_patch( Rectangle((bf - tw/2, 0), tw, h, fc ='black',zorder=2 ) ) 
ax.add_patch( Rectangle((0 - tw/2, 0), tw, h, fc ='black',zorder=2 ) ) 

plt.title('Ejemplo', size = 24, fontweight='bold')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlabel('X_axis\nColocar este pequeño subtítulo por debajo del eje x pero con letra cursiva', size = 24)
plt.ylabel('Y_axis', size = 24)

figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()

plt.show()
```

A modo de ilustración mostraré dos gráficas con lo que tengo y lo que quiero:

[image: Ilustrar]

Sería de gran ayuda que me puedan dar su aporte para resolver este pequeño tema, saludos cordiales.

Comment: Prueba encerrando el texto entre "$\it{" y "}$", asi `plt.title('$\it{texto a mostrar en itálica}$')`

Comment: Muy buena solución, muchas gracias. Ahora si quisiera modificar el tamaño de letra qué método usaría sólo para esa línea. También me podrías ayudar con la documentación de estos métodos de encerrar texto? Ya que no los he visto. Saludos @CandidMoe

Comment: No conozco matplot, asi que consulto en Google, pruebo las respuesta y eso ...